# How can I use 64-bit integers on a PIC18?

Tags: pic, xc8

When I try to declare either a `unsigned long long` or a `uint64_t` the `xc8` compiler throws the following warning:

```
    12: uint64_t overflow_time;
             ^ (374) missing basic type; int assumed (warning)
             ^ (314) ";" expected
                          ^ (374) missing basic type; int assumed (warning)
```

This eventually spirals into an error later in the compilation. Through some research I found that when using the default C90 standard the `xc8` compiler doesn't support 64-bit datatypes.

The best solution I could find [online](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1091489.aspx) was "Upgrade to XC8 2.05" - which I already had.

How can I get the compiler to allow me to use 64 bit datatypes?

Comment: Just ***don't*** use 64 bit numbers on the least code efficient CPU still manufactured. Never. If you for reasons unknown need 64 bit resolution, you picked the completely wrong MCU for the task. You are essentially asking how to fit an elephant inside a porcelain store. Just because it is theoretically possible by temporary removing some wall, that doesn't mean it is a good idea or something you should be doing.

Comment: What in the world are you doing that calls for a 64-bit integer?  That's a very big number!!  You might be better off asking about achieving what you want to achieve with a smaller integer.

Comment: @Lundin, that's a strange stipulation. Practically any CPU can handle very large numbers absolutely fine if performance is not a problem, which OP didn't say was a concern. And large data on small or very low cost CPUs is very common. All depends on the requirements of the application, as with every design: cost, availability, performance, familiarity with tools, cost, commonality with other designs, cost. And cost, usually :-)

Comment: @TonyM To begin with, the software libs needed to perform 64 bit arithmetic could be larger than the whole flash available on the dinosaur PIC. And the dead horse argument about 8 bitters still being cheaper is obsolete since some 15 years back. And if you look at MIPS/$, PIC is probably the most expensive CPU on the market.

Comment: @Lundin Doing some 64 bit addition on my PIC18F47K42 uses <4.5% of the data memory and <1.1% of the program memory...

Comment: @Lundin, OP's CPU can perform 64-bit addition fine. Or 1024-bit. You're inventing a performance/space problem to solve. The world uses mountains of 8-bit CPUs, some in high-volume, very low-cost applications. They forget MIPS/$, all about tiny $. (We've disagreed about this before and are getting nowhere here. Look wider, it's a far diverser market than just mainstream Europe/US supplier price lists.)

Comment: @TonyM I'm not "inventing" anything, I despise 8 bit MCUs because I have written code for them for nearly 20 years and unlike the Arudino hordes, I closely monitor performance and disassembly of my programs. Most people still use 8 bit MCUs not because of cost, but because they don't know better. They are code inefficient in general, but specifically they are deadly slow at handling larger integers, not to mention floating point. They have weird addressing/banking rules, they have weird limitations (like PIC stack depth), they are vulnerable to C integer promotion bugs. And so on and so on.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sure you think you know what's best but there are many considerations beyond what *you* want. Maybe I'm working in a existing system and I have to use the same chip? Maybe I want to use the micro because I've worked with them before and therefore there is less of a time cost? Maybe I care most about low power (9nA << 30nA)? You were wrong about the space cost - just accept that and move on. No need to get off-topic.

Comment: @HarryBeadle Unless you happen to have 177 bytes data memory and  727 bytes of program memory, you proved that I am right yourself: "Doing some 64 bit addition on my PIC18F47K42 uses <4.5% of the data memory and <1.1% of the program memory".  A reasonable system would use 8 bytes data and roughly twice the amount for the instructions. "Maybe I want to use the micro because I've worked with them before and therefore there is less of a time cost?" Yes that's exactly why these are still used. Someone found a PIC in a packet of corn flakes 20 years ago. From there on refuses to learn new things.

Comment: @Lundin "reasonable system"? Surely a reasonable system is one that does it's job with the least work and lowest cost? (Keep in mind that number also includes a 128-byte (on both tx and rx) buffered UART.) I literally used a 16-bit dsPIC on a project less than a month ago. My point is you don't know the application, you don't know best, and **context matters**. I'm done with this now - thanks for the warm welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

64-bit datatypes are available to use but you must use the following flags when compiling:

```
--std=C99 --ext=cci
```

This makes the compiler use the C99 standard with the Common C Interface. With these compiler flags you will be able to use 64-bit integers.

**However**, it may require you to reformat your code as some C90 code will not play nicely with C99. It is worth searching through the [Compiler Handbook](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf) for "CCI" too, as this also changes how you have to format your code (notably for interrupts).

Comment: Maybe have also a look here about xc8 2.0 and up:https://microchipdeveloper.com/xc8:whats-new-in-xc8-2-0